# How to select images in carousel in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a carousel in Reactjs in which there are some fruits images. Now how can I select or deselect multiple images? I used ImagePicker but it is allowing only one image to select. I tried very much, googled it but I couldn't find any solution. Can someone help me, please? This is the picture of the carousel.[carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiYal.png)

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./cropSelection.css";
import Carousel, { Dots } from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';
import ImagePicker from 'react-image-picker';
import 'react-image-picker/dist/index.css'
import Select from 'react-select'
import img1 from './assets/x5a1c46753530787968003715118024852179.png';
import img2 from './assets/kisspngCommonGuavaTropicalFruitStrawberryGuavaGuava5abf7f16ed8bf1981749341522499350973.png';
import img3 from './assets/kisspngFrescaCitronLemonFruitTangeloGreenMangoOnGreenLeaves5a83ea37e27f718808719715185946159277.png';
import img4 from './assets/x5a1c46753530787968003715118024852179.png';
import img5 from './assets/kisspngCommonGuavaTropicalFruitStrawberryGuavaGuava5abf7f16ed8bf1981749341522499350973.png';

const imageList1 = [img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img1]
class Crop extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    slides:[ 
           (<ImagePicker 
            images={imageList1.map((image1, i) => ({src: image1, value: i}))}/>), 
            //  (<ImagePicker 
            // images={imageList1.map((img, i) => ({src: img, value: i}))}
            // onPick={() => this.onPick()}/> ),

        ]
  }
}

render(){
  return(
   <div className="caurosel-div">

   <Carousel
    arrows
    slidesPerScroll={1}
    slidesPerPage={3}
    value={this.state.value}
    slides={this.state.slides}
    onChange={this.onchange}
    >

    {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => console.log(this.state.image)}>OK</button> */}

     </Carousel>
    <button className="button">Proceed</button>
    </div>

);
}
}
export default Crop;
```

Comment: I don't see the source code for this listed on npm or a quick google search. Have you tried implementing the `onPick(Image)` function? What does it do? I'm sure you can debug it fairly quickly. The project claims to support multiple image selection and I suspect you need to handle it. I also suspect that your `Carousel` component is implementing an `onClick` handler that's firing before the `ImagePicker` works. You can verify this through VisualEvent or debugging it in the browser. There is a high probability these projects are incompatible as is. You might try writing your own.

Comment: Yes, I used onPick() but it is not working for me.

Comment: Debug it, look at the `onClick` events, I suspect that `Carousel` implements an `onClick` handler so your `ImagePicker` never fires. You might be able to pass an event down from the Carousel . Alternatively implement your own. I didn't do any serious debugging but https://github.com/brainhubeu/react-carousel/blob/474bd43cb1e52148a75b9938c21801fc6080a927/src/components/CarouselItem.js#L46 seems to indicate the `onTouchStart` event is used and is probably blocking your clicks.